# jQuery how to select button with specific text

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button in a dialog, the dialog is built on a div, the div has an id.  I've tried this:

```
    $("#idOfDiv button:contains(\"Submit\")").trigger("click");
```

This is called in a keypress handler when the "Enter" key is pressed.  Unfortunately it doesn't work.  The HTML looks something like this:

```
      <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-osx ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" 
         style="height: auto; width: 320px; top: 526px; left: 543px; display: block;"
         tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
         aria-describedby="selindividual" 
         aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
        <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle">
          <span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">
            Select Individual
          </span>
          <button type="button" 
                  class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close"
                  role="button" 
                  title="Close">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="idOfDiv" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 48px;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"><div class="dialog-panel">
          <p class="dlgline">Select individual:
            <select id="biPersonID">
              <option value="0">Create new resume</option>
              <option value="1">Name A</option>
              <option value="2">Name B</option>
            </select>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
          <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Submit</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Edit]  Maybe its the event handler? :

```
    $("#idOfDiv").keypress(function(e) {
      if ( e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER ) {
        $("#idOfDiv button:contains(\"Submit\")").trigger("click");
      }
    });
```

[Edit#2] I'm using Mozilla and its Developer Tools to debug this, if I set a watch on the expression:

```
    $("#idOfDiv button:contains(\"Submit\")")
```

In the Watch expressions panel I see the watch and expand it shows:

```
    context: HTMLDocument http://localhost:8000/?cnt=ceresume
    length: 0
    prevObject: {...}
    selector: "#idOfDiv button:contains(\"Submit\")"
    <prototype>: {...}
```

The length: 0 tells me it isn't correct.

[Edit#3] I'm using the jQuery dialog classes:

```
    $("#idOfDiv").dialog({modal:true
                     ,draggable:true
                     ,resizable:false
                      ,position:{my:"center", at:"center", of:window}
                          ,show:"blind"
                          ,hide:"blind"
                         ,height:140
                          ,width:320
                    ,dialogClass:"ui-dialog-osx"
                        ,buttons:{"Submit":function() {
    /* Stuff to do on submit */
    }}});
```

Comment: Please, include in the question the JS code responsible for the keypress. Also, *`$("#idOfDiv...`* is meant to refers to which div?

Comment: Your idea is correct, `$("#zzz button:contains('Submit')").click()` should trigger the click event in your example html, but there is something missing in your execution that you haven't provided and therefore your question can't be answered.

Comment: If you're trying to submit an actual form, then you might be best to just submit the form with javascript, instead of clicking the button `$('.input').keypress(function (e) { if (e.which == 13) { $('#yourFormID').submit(); return false; } });`

Comment: Your #idOfDiv doesn't contain a button so therefore it can't have anything containing 'Submit'. You need to add a new id in the parent container of the button you wish to search for and click

Comment: @Keith,I'll edit post again to show why it should be ok.

Comment: @Keith, I think you have hit the problem, because after calling .dialog, it puts the buttons outside of the div containing the id I've specified.

Comment: Something else to, $.ui.keyCode.ENTER doesn't seem to render the enter button. Why not use something like var enter = 13; which the Enter key equals?

Comment: @Keith, If I hover the mouse over the definition it shows 13 so the constant is ok.

Comment: Is there anyway to use the id of my dialog and walk back up a number of tags to get to the buttons?

Comment: Sure, you can either do .closest('.class') or do .parent() or .parents() to walk it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is something missing in your code you haven't shown, but using a filter works for me.

```
<div id="idOfDiv" class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
   <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
     <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" onclick="alert('works')">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Submit</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>

var getID = $("#idOfDiv button");
if(getID.filter(':contains("Submit")').length > 0){
   console.log('hit');
   getID.click();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4xndmor9/

Comment: you are correct, but the dialog doesn't add the buttons inside the div with the ID its called, instead it creates wrapping divs around it and places the buttons outside of the div id I'm using.

Answer (score 3):

There is a missing parenthesis and closing double quote in:

```
$("#idOfDiv button:contains(\"Submit\").trigger("click");
                                    ^^^
```

The correct format is:

```
$("#idOfDiv button:contains(\"Submit\")").trigger("click");
                                      ^^
```

According to your updated answer, you are looking for a button containing a specific text under the next element. Hence, the select is:

```
$("#idOfDiv").next('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains(\"Submit\")")
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo when I created the post...I'll edit the post to correct.

Comment: @SPlatten  Ok. Now let me know  where the **idOfDiv ** element is.